# If X has a pdf $f(x)=2xe^{-x^2}$ $x>0$ Show that E(X)=$\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, symmetry

It says that you can use the symmetry of the normal standard distribution and that $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \! \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2} \, dx = 1$
to show that E(X)=$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \! e^{-x^2} \, dx =\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} $

I was trying to transform E(X)=$ \int_{0}^{\infty}  \! 2xe^{-x^2} \, dx $ into

$\int_{0}^{\infty}  \! \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{e^{-x^2}}{2}} \, dx $
to use the symmetry but i couldn't make it.

Could you help me?

Comment: The derivative of $e^{-x^2}$ is $-2xe^{-x^2}$ which makes $\int_{0}^{\infty}  \! 2xe^{-x^2} \, dx =1$.  But this is the total probability of the distribution, not the expectation.  For that, you might want to use integration by parts

Comment: $E[X] = \int_0^\infty x\cdot 2x \exp(-x^2) \,\mathrm dx$ and not what you write. Set $v=x, \mathrm du = 2x \exp(-x^2), u = -\exp(-x^2)$ and use integration by parts as suggested by Henry. You will need to know the value of $\int_0^\infty  \exp(-x^2) \,\mathrm dx$ or to be able to  do a change of variables to get a Gamma function and then evaluate it, or do a change of variables in $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \! \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2} \, dx$ to deduce the value of $\int_0^\infty  \exp(-x^2) \,\mathrm dx$.